# How am I able to call a method on a null object?

Tags: java

```
public class JavaPuzzler {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaPuzzler javaPuzzler = null;
    System.out.println(javaPuzzler.get());
    }
     
    private static String get(){
        return "i am a java puzzler";
    }
}
```

You might think that it should throw NullPointerException because the main method invokes get() method  on **local variable which is initialized
to null**, and you can’t invoke a method on null.

**But if you run this program, you will see that it prints “i am a java puzzler”.**

Comment: I think in your print statement its JavaPuzzler.get() with capital J

Comment: @Nikunj question is absolutely right there is not any mistake in word.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan, no, the code is correct and will run as posted...lowercase 'j' and all.  Apparently you and your two upvoters didn't try it out first :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code sample, `get()` is a *static member* that belongs to the class, not to an instance. You do not need an instance in order to invoke the method.

```
public static String get() // belongs globally to class, no instance required
public String get() // belongs to instance
```

Comment: This seems kind of wrong that it calls a static method on an (albeit `null`) instance variable. Interesting, though.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: If you try the code in eclipse, it will automatically be changed to Class.call() from instance.call()

Answer (score 4):

It's because the method is static and though you reference an instance, the instance isn't necessary.  The Java Language Specification explains why in [section 8.4.3.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.2):

> A method that is declared static is called a class method. A class
>   method is always invoked without reference to a particular object.

This means that it does not matter if `javaPuzzler` instance is null - the method "belongs" to the class, not an instance.

Answer (score 3):

The `get` method is static, which means that the actual reference in `javaPuzzler` is ignored in that call, only the variable's type is used.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is static. So it could only be called in a static way.

So even though you are putting it as javaPuzzler.get(), actual call will be JavaPuzzler.get() and thus the printing!!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a static methode, you dont need an instance to call it, thats why it works.

Answer (score 1):

If we try calling a method using NULL object it will throw `NullPointerException` as long as the method is not static.

If method is static it will run.

Read [HERE](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/null.html) for more reference

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone mentions here, it works because `get()` is a static method. Here's a way that you can think about this:

When you define a class in Java, what you're essentially doing is defining the data that an object will hold, and a set of methods that operate on that data. Now while you can have thousands and thousands of objects, it doesn't make sense to have copies of all the methods for each of them. What happens is that the class stores the methods you define, and executes them in the *scope* of the object that you call the method on. If you attempt to call these methods on an uninitialized object, the object still exists and the method still exists, but it has no valid to scope to work on, thus giving you the `NullPointerException`.

The exception to this rule is static methods, which are methods that don't need a scope - they don't refer to object-specific data. This is why they can run irrespective of whether the object is initialized or not.

Just remember that objects don't have copies of their methods... the methods are just called in the scope of the object's data. So you can still access the methods of null (uninitialized) objects, but non-static methods have no data to work on.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler changes the instance call to a class call automatically. If you have a decompiler you can observe the change in the generated byte code:

```
...
 public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    ACONST_NULL
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 9 L1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    INVOKESTATIC JavaPuzzler.get()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 11 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE javaPuzzler LJavaPuzzler; L1 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you have given get() function as static. Static functions and data members do no belong to any object. They belong to the class. You can call static function using object of class but thats not a good approach as it consumes extra memory.

Since static, JavaPuzzler.get()); will give you the output and not null pointer exception.

It would have given null pointer exception in case the get() method would have been non static.